# Retrieving data from Excel in C#

Tags: c#, database, excel, database-connection, export-to-excel

I'm using an Excel workbook as database, my code in C# WinForms and already writes on each Excel column and filters the Text from letters, etc.

But I have one problem, when I double click N times "add" button, it writes N times the same information.

I need my program to be able to make someking of filtering before adding, I mean, if I'm trying to add the same information twice the program would make the information visible in my textboxes, how would I be able to do that? I've tried many things on the net, but none of them work.

Please help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about excel as database, but following may be helpfull:

1. Add hidden ID - as a Guid.
2. In handler check if this ID was added
3. Add only if ID was not found in Excel.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer.
Do you suggest me to add the Guid in my C# code or directly on Excel? I've been searching for that, but I haven't found out wich one is better.